# How can I make my external monitor the default monitor for games?

Tags: windows, macbook-pro, sleep, external-display

When I boot into Windows on my Macbook Pro, I am unable to make the external monitor the default monitor.

So when I play games full screen, they automatically open up on my laptop monitor. I want them to open up on my secondary monitor. The only solution I found to this is to make my external monitor mirror my laptop monitor.

I can't even close the lid of the laptop monitor because that will cause the system to go to sleep.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

From [Kioskea.net](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-181212-how-to-make-my-external-screen-the-primary)

> right click on desktop
>
> then to display properties
>
> now on this tab you will get the
>   generic
>
> or default monitor change the monitor
>   there

Also from [Kioskea.net](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-12915-external-monitor-for-laptop)

> Just right click the desktop and choose graphics options/external monitor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problems once. What kind of gpu is your MBP using? Ati or Nvidia? In case it's Ati, I think there is a website that offers modified catalyst control center version that work in bootcamp. With the modified ccc installed I was able to set my default monitor to the external. Unfortunately I can't provide you with any links because I'm traveling right now.